# Adding a field to queryset in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a model whose fields are datetimefields start_time and end_time
I want to display on the API- start_time, end_time and the difference between them
However, I don't want to use for or while loop to achieve this because it is too slow
How can I get the difference on the API without looping

Comment: I don't get why looping is too slow. Django will loop as well since it retrieves the data from the database, and will do looping to "pack" the data in model objects.

Comment: Have you tried something like this, `ModelKlass.objects.annotate(diff=F('field_1')-F('field_2'))` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: the problem is that this is that Django's "type system" does not reason this to be a `DurationField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the queryset with the difference, and then use an `ExpressionWrapper` to convert this to a `DurationField`, and thus obtain a `timedelta` objects:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    time_diff=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('end_time')-F('start_time'),
        output_field=DurationField()
    )
)
```

The `MyModel`s that arise from *this* queryset will thus have an extra attribute `time_diff` that is a `timedelta` field containing the difference between `end_time`, and `start_time`.